# Why does the ProgressBar animation misbehave when adding it after the parent view has been laid out?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar, layout-inflater

I have an `Activity` with only a `Button` and a `LinearLayout`. Every time the button is clicked, a newly inflated view is added to the `LinearLayout` via `addView()`. The added view is a single `ProgressBar`.

When adding new views after the `LinearLayout` has been laid out, the `ProgressBar` animation behaves weirdly, doing only part of the spin. However, when adding new views before the `LinearLayout` has been laid out (in the `Activity`'s `onCreate()`), all of them behave normally.

Why does this happen? Is there any way to fix the problem? The problem only seems to appear on Android 5.x, it works as expected in newer versions. Maybe it's a platform bug, but I think this is a rather simple use case, and provided that there is no info about it on the Internet, maybe it's something I am doing wrong. But what is it?

Here is the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout mainLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        //These three views will display the correct ProgressBar animation
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            addElement();
        }

        findViewById(R.id.add_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //These views will NOT display the correct ProgressBar animation
                //(on Android 5.0 or 5.1)
                addElement();
            }
        });
    }

    private void addElement() {
        View childView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.test_element, null);
        mainLayout.addView(childView);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add view" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**test_element.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is the behavior right now (the first three are the ones added before the view is laid out):

[image: Current app behavior]

Thanks!

Comment: Try to call  `addElement();` in `Handler` with some amount of time delay.

Comment: I tried doing `mainLayout.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);` (calling `addElement()` inside the `Runnable`), and the same problem occurs.